# I'm confused with the use 'for'

Tags: grammar

In the following sentence, I'm confused with the use 'for'. Please explain it.

> The respect among ourselves, our people, and **for** other people from all over the world will make our nation a better place to live in.

Comment: Please [tell us where this sentence came from](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1084/so-you-found-a-sentence-or-phrase-why-you-should-cite-your-source).

Answer (score 1):

**respect for somebody/something** is idiomatic and in the following sentence it is used correctly.

You can parse your sentence as,

> The respect among ourselves, our people, and ***(the respect)*** for other people from all over the world will make our nation a better place to live in.

Answer (score 1):

- The respect among ourselves, our people
- The respect for other people

Different prepositions are used here for two reasons:

- “respect for ourselves” could mean individual self-respect; the point is about respect for each other, reciprocally.
- “respect among other people” is not our concern; our duty is *our* respect for them, whether or not they respect each other. *We* cannot give respect *among* others, any more than I can (on my own) make an agreement between you two.

By the way, I interpret *ourselves, our people* as a clarifying apposition – *our people* being synonymous with *ourselves* – rather than separate items in a list; because if you give prepositions to two of the items, you must give them to all, or wreck the parallelism.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit confusing!

In the sentence, there are three groups: *ourselves*, *our people*, and *other people from all over the world*.

These groups are divided into two categories: "Us" (*ourselves* and *our people*) and "not us" (*other people from all over the world*).

*Ourselves* is a specific subgroup of *our people*, presumably with a common culture, nationality, or some other feature which makes them a single category distinct from other categories.

The sentence is describing the *behavior* or *condition* of the first group only, and suggests that that behavior is *directed* at both groups:

> The respect among ourselves, our people

Immediately following *ourselves* with *our people* suggests that *the respect* applies to both groups similarly. So both *ourselves* and *our people* are described by *the respect*. *Among* suggests that *the respect* is commonly present or commonly demonstrated between all members of the "us" category.

But when it comes to the final group the sentence does not suggest that *other people from all over the world* have a similar degree of *the respect* among them-- that group may not be very respectful, or have much respect (in the same sense as the first two groups are described). The sentence says nothing about what this group is like or how it behaves with regard to *respect*. However, the first two groups *treat* the third group with respect:

> *respect for* other people from all over the world

The first two groups are not simply respectful in general, they direct that respect towards the third group.

Comment: I don't think the sentence is saying that there is a different degree of respect. I think the writer (or speaker) is simply saying there is respect _among ourselves, among our people, and for other people_, and simply felt the need to change the preposition to make the sentence flow better. It's similar to saying something like, _He could hear the noises **in** the kitchen, the basement, and **on** the roof_. The preposition "in" works fine with _basement_ but not with _roof_.

Comment: @J.R. Definitely possible as a matter of intention. But as written the sentence indicates direction: *ourselves* and *our people* have respect *for other people […]*. It makes no statement about what *other people* are like, and simply describes something about *ourselves* and *our people*. The sentence would read as you suggest if *for* were entirely omitted, but it is present.

Answer (score 0):

If you can say "X is kept and then later given or provided Y", you can say "X is for Y."

> This food is kept and then later given when dinner happens.
>
> This food is for dinner.

*Respect* works the same as above, even though it's not a physical object that kept and then later given.